# adjust div height on load new page from menu

Tags: html, menu, resize

i'm triing to load the various page of the site on main div, but the div don't resize on load.

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="home.html" target="iframe_a">Home</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="servizi.html" target="iframe_a">Servizi</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="progetti.html" target="iframe_a">Progettazione</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="./servizi/wip.html" target="iframe_a">Urbanistica</a></li>
                    <li><a href="./servizi/wip.html" target="iframe_a">Edilizia</a></li>
                    <li><a href="./servizi/wip.html" target="iframe_a">Abbattimento barriere architettoniche</a></li>
                </ul>
...
...
...
```

this is a section of menu

and this is the div (previously was an iframe but don't work equally)

```
<div> 
<object type="text/html" data="home.html" name="iframe_a" id="iframe_a" width=80% height="600px" min-height:"600px" style="overflow:hidden;border:5px ridge blue">
    </object>
</div>
```

if i remove the height="600px" the div is about 100px end don't modify it's height on change

all the page i'm trying to load onto the main div are "simple" just

```
<body> 
<div> 
text/image of the page with <p> etc..
</div>
</body>
```

no special effect or something.

were i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For responsive re-size you should really be using % for both width and height
from your code for example

`<div> 
<object type="text/html" data="home.html" name="iframe_a" id="iframe_a" width=80% height="60%" min-height:"600px" style="overflow:hidden;border:5px ridge blue">
    </object>
</div>`

You may also want to consider revising your border size to suit the smallest resolution you want to use in the re-size.

Comment: doesen't work, after opening the main page the div resize it'self at something around 100px height and loading different page don't resize the div

Comment: Sorry I did not get back sooner I was away Whats the URL of your Page and I'll take a look?